# How custom ui (using photoshop-like programs) can be added to an android app project?

Tags: android, user-interface, photoshop

I see so many apps that their ui designed using photoshop-like programs, i just was asking about how custom UIs (something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XT-SoZa6V_Q)) that have been designed using such programs can be imported to android app project (for example) , and combined like what we can see in a good designed apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user3446273, photoshop is only a design tool to create the look and feel of the APP UI. To replicate or use the UI in your android project, you can export parts of the UI as PNGs and include them in the android project.

In most cases, people slice relevant portions (example: icons, buttons) of the UI in photoshop and save the slices as JPG or PNG. These JPG or PNG files are imported into Android project code.

Before you start designing the UI, it is recommended that you read the [Android UI guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [Material design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html). The Photoshop just design image for your style app. May be jpg, png, gif,... Example the progress you share this link. I think u can't not style for your app just only with Photoshop or like programs.

Comment: design using material design principles is a specific issue, i mean in general, some apps (like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer.unlock&hl=en) for example) have amazing ui, i'm sure that the developers using photoshop-like programs to design such ui, but how can they import it into the app and make it interact with the user with so many effects?

Comment: if u want use many effects u can use animation. I have not seen anyone using Photoshop to design the UI for Android. They just use photoshop to design the images used in the animation and style (xml)

Answer (score 0):

Generally designers use photoshop to design a new layouts.They follow the guidelines of google material design for android and guidelines for ios.They have to design apps in all sizes respective to phone resolutions for eg lets say  iphone 6 plus ,its resolution is 1080x1920 but designers have to built 1242x2208.They use their creatvity and design apps.Then they have to slice icons,buttons,images,backgrounds .. etc so i hope you got your answer